# java xpath searching for a text

Tags: java, xpath

Following is a part of an XML file. I need to find all nodes that have a score associated with it and all SimplePredicates lead to each score to generate a rule set
Example:

```
if  (GRAVH.1 <= 2751.5996775) && (WV.unity <= 93.567676535) && (Zagreb <= 74)
{
score = 2.32
}
```

Is it possible to do this with java xpath
Here is the XML File..

```
 </MiningSchema>
         <Node id="1">
          <True/>
          <Node id="2">
           <SimplePredicate field="GRAVH.1" operator="lessOrEqual" value="2751.5996775"/>
           <Node id="4">
            <SimplePredicate field="WV.unity" operator="lessOrEqual" value="93.567676535"/>
            <Node id="8">
             <SimplePredicate field="Zagreb" operator="lessOrEqual" value="74"/>
             <Node id="16" score="2.32">
              <SimplePredicate field="VP.0" operator="lessOrEqual" value="6.047602111"/>
             </Node>
             <Node id="17">
              <SimplePredicate field="VP.0" operator="greaterThan" value="6.047602111"/>
              <Node id="28" score="2.832">
               <SimplePredicate field="MOMI.Y" operator="lessOrEqual" value="838.9644494"/>
              </Node>
              <Node id="29" score="3.1075">
               <SimplePredicate field="MOMI.Y" operator="greaterThan" value="838.9644494"/>
              </Node>
             </Node>
            </Node>
            <Node id="9">
             <SimplePredicate field="Zagreb" operator="greaterThan" value="74"/>
             <Node id="18" score="3.4">
              <SimplePredicate field="SP.0" operator="lessOrEqual" value="11.10848385"/>
             </Node>
             <Node id="19">
              <SimplePredicate field="SP.0" operator="greaterThan" value="11.10848385"/>
              <Node id="30" score="3.81333333333333">
               <SimplePredicate field="MobCSA" operator="lessOrEqual" value="135.12"/>
              </Node>
              <Node id="31" score="4.04">
               <SimplePredicate field="MobCSA" operator="greaterThan" value="135.12"/>
              </Node>
             </Node>
            </Node>
           </Node>
           <Node id="5">
            <SimplePredicate field="WV.unity" operator="greaterThan" value="93.567676535"/>
            <Node id="10">
             <SimplePredicate field="VP.7" operator="lessOrEqual" value="0.583140169"/>
             <Node id="20">
              <SimplePredicate field="apol" operator="lessOrEqual" value="50.9146355"/>
              <Node id="32" score="4.48">
               <SimplePredicate field="MOMI.Z" operator="lessOrEqual" value="791.5388999"/>
              </Node>
              <Node id="33" score="4.848">
               <SimplePredicate field="MOMI.Z" operator="greaterThan" value="791.5388999"/>
              </Node>
             </Node>
             <Node id="21" score="5.14">
              <SimplePredicate field="apol" operator="greaterThan" value="50.9146355"/>
             </Node>
            </Node>
            <Node id="11">
             <SimplePredicate field="VP.7" operator="greaterThan" value="0.583140169"/>
             <Node id="22">
              <SimplePredicate field="WPATH" operator="lessOrEqual" value="1502"/>
              <Node id="34" score="5.638">
               <SimplePredicate field="WPATH" operator="lessOrEqual" value="1440.5"/>
              </Node>
              <Node id="35" score="5.45">
               <SimplePredicate field="WPATH" operator="greaterThan" value="1440.5"/>
              </Node>
             </Node>
             <Node id="23" score="5.922">
              <SimplePredicate field="WPATH" operator="greaterThan" value="1502"/>
             </Node>
            </Node>
           </Node>
          </Node>
          <Node id="3">
           <SimplePredicate field="GRAVH.1" operator="greaterThan" value="2751.5996775"/>
           <Node id="6">
            <SimplePredicate field="ECCEN" operator="lessOrEqual" value="849"/>
            <Node id="12">
             <SimplePredicate field="MOMI.Y" operator="lessOrEqual" value="8736.7661745"/>
             <Node id="24" score="6.37">
              <SimplePredicate field="MOMI.R" operator="lessOrEqual" value="8.2680425545"/>
             </Node>
             <Node id="25" score="6.7925">
              <SimplePredicate field="MOMI.R" operator="greaterThan" value="8.2680425545"/>
             </Node>
            </Node>
            <Node id="13" score="7.61">
             <SimplePredicate field="MOMI.Y" operator="greaterThan" value="8736.7661745"/>
            </Node>
           </Node>
           <Node id="7">
            <SimplePredicate field="ECCEN" operator="greaterThan" value="849"/>
            <Node id="14">
             <SimplePredicate field="WA.unity" operator="lessOrEqual" value="198.5991815"/>
             <Node id="26" score="7.94">
              <SimplePredicate field="SP.3" operator="lessOrEqual" value="11.61334328"/>
             </Node>
             <Node id="27">
              <SimplePredicate field="SP.3" operator="greaterThan" value="11.61334328"/>
              <Node id="36" score="8.75">
               <SimplePredicate field="MDEC.13" operator="lessOrEqual" value="6.9421166205"/>
              </Node>
              <Node id="37" score="8.42">
               <SimplePredicate field="MDEC.13" operator="greaterThan" value="6.9421166205"/>
              </Node>
             </Node>
            </Node>
            <Node id="15" score="9.408">
             <SimplePredicate field="WA.unity" operator="greaterThan" value="198.5991815"/>
            </Node>
           </Node>
          </Node>
         </Node>
        </TreeModel>
       </Segment>
       <Segment id="3">
```

Comment: try googling on `conditional xpath expression`

Comment: This question is quite undefined: 1. The "XML" provided isn't a well-formed XML document. 2. Nothing is said what should be the result of the processing. ... Please, edit the question and provide the information necessary to make it more meaningful. Failing to do so may result in answers that are unexpected and not useful to you.

Comment: The idea is to generate a rule set (java source code) based on the decision trees stored in the XML file. The file is too large to be attached (close to 90000 lines)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
//node[@score]
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you already tried ? This is what you can try:

1. Get the ancestors of your node with `//Node[@id='16']/ancestor::Node`
2. Iterate over that NodeList and create the ruleset as you read the attributes of nodes
3. when on last ancestor get the final Node and retrieve the score from it
4. print what you have found

Here is a sample using only standard jdk, but you may be tempted to use something like [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/):

```
public class SO9466408 {
    private static final Map<String, String> OP = new HashMap<String, String>() {{ put("lessOrEqual", "<="); }};

    public static String attrValue(Node node, String attrName) {
        return node.getAttributes().getNamedItem(attrName).getTextContent();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException {
        final String id = "16";
        String score = null;
        final StringBuilder ruleset = new StringBuilder("if (");
        // XML/XPath
        final InputSource xmlInput = new InputSource(new URL("your file.xml").openStream());
        final XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        // get the ancestors node
        final XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Node[@id='" + id + "']/ancestor::Node");
        final NodeList ancestors = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(xmlInput, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int i = 0; i < ancestors.getLength(); ++i) {
            Node predicate = ancestors.item(i).getFirstChild();
            // get a new rule
            if (predicate.getNodeName().equals("SimplePredicate")) {
                ruleset.append(String.format("%s(%s %s %s)", i > 1 ? " && " : "", 
                        attrValue(predicate, "field"), OP.get(attrValue(predicate, "operator")), attrValue(predicate, "value")));
            }
            // retrieve the score on the last node
            if (i == ancestors.getLength() - 1) {
                score = attrValue((Node) xpath.compile("//Node[@id='" + id + "']").evaluate(ancestors.item(i), XPathConstants.NODE), "score");
            }
        }
        // show what we found
        ruleset.append(") {\n\tscore = " + score + ";\n}");
        System.out.println(ruleset.toString());
    }
}

// Outputs:
// if  ((GRAVH.1 <= 2751.5996775) && (WV.unity <= 93.567676535) && (Zagreb <= 74))
// {
//     score = 2.32
// }
```

Comment: Alex, thanks for the answer. I will try your method and let you know how it goes..